# How to support multi language in GSON (between Json and Java Object)?

Tags: java, json, gson, httprequest

In my project , i separated back-end and front-end modules and run by providing REST api from back-end and call it by using Apache Http Client and GSON.

I want to provide multiple language like German,French... on UI(webpage).

On webpage , It shows like this "Schl��ssli Sch��negg, Wilhelmsh��he" , but in database and RestAPI json is "Schlössli Schönegg" .

How can I support multi language?

In back-end , i wrote Request methods like get,put,post and In Front-end, i used HttpClient and GSON to convert JSON to/from Java Object.

I tried  inside the html but main problem is from GSON when it convert fromJSON() , the original JSON value ""Schlössli Schönegg" become "Schl��ssli Sch��negg, Wilhelmsh��he".

In RestAPI  , JSON data is

{
        "addressId": 3,
        "buildingName": "Schlössli Schönegg",
        "street": "Wilhelmshöhe",
        "ward": "6003",
        "district": "luzern",
        "cityOrProvince": "luzern state",
        "country": "Switzerland"
 }

But in Front-end , Java Object String Data after GSON convert is

(..buildingName=SchlÃ¶ssli SchÃ¶negg, street=WilhelmshÃ¶he, ward=6003, district=luzern, cityOrProvince=luzern state, country=Switzerland)

Here , RestClient function code

```
public List<FakeEmployeeDTO> getAllEmployeeList() throws IOException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

    Integer statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        throw new SystemException(ERROR_MESSAGE + statusCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        jsonData.append(line);
    }
    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
    rd.close();
    logger.info(jsonData.toString());

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").create();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<FakeEmployeeDTO>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<FakeEmployeeDTO> employeeList = gson.fromJson(jsonData.toString(), listType);
    sortEmployeeListByFirstName(employeeList);
    return employeeList;
}
```

Inside Employee, I have address atrribute , inside that address i have value like buildingNumber and Street, that value can be in any languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
(BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),
       "UTF-8"));)
```

Entire Code will end up with like this.

```
public List<FakeEmployeeDTO> getAllEmployeeList() throws IOException {

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

Integer statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (statusCode != 200) {
    throw new SystemException(ERROR_MESSAGE + statusCode);
}
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),
    "UTF-8"));  // if it is not working please try with ("ISO-8859-1")
String line = "";
StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    jsonData.append(line);
}
response.getEntity().getContent().close();
rd.close();
logger.info(jsonData.toString());

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").create();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<FakeEmployeeDTO>>() {
}.getType();
List<FakeEmployeeDTO> employeeList = gson.fromJson(jsonData.toString(), listType);
sortEmployeeListByFirstName(employeeList);
return employeeList;}
```

Next time make sure to  try with this, because you can use "try with resource"

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new URL("https://htt.your url.com" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8") )
                            .openConnection().getInputStream()))) {
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you for answer. I will try it. I think it will be work in one way . I forget about InputStreamReader , just notice it now when u said. Thank you again